# Generate a C struct based on a complex Haskell type

Tags: c, haskell, ffi

I am trying to use a Haskell library in my C code. The Haskell function I am trying to use has the type `String -> IO [Reference]` where `Reference` is a rather complex structure (see [here for details](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/citeproc-hs/0.3.6/doc/html/Text-CSL-Reference.html#t:Reference)).

Based on reading various pieces of documentation it seems that I would have to make this type an instance of `Storable` and also have a similar struct defined in my c code to be able to access it. This seems like a lot of very repetitive work for such a complex type. Is there a way to automate this? How would one go about doing such a thing?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but [hsc2hs](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.4.1/html/users_guide/hsc2hs.html) can help you write `Storable` instances for types that have a corresponding C struct.

Comment: Yeah I would need somewhat the opposite - something that writes me a C struct based on a Haskell type.

Comment: I expect that the difficult part in automating it is in deciding, in full generality, how to translate a Haskell data type into C. It looks like your type is large, but not very complicated--non-recursive and built from either single constructor types with named fields or enumeration types. Translating that to C would be entirely straightforward.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on you actual use case, but...
It could be easier to export `Reference` as opaque type (via [Foreign.StablePtr](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.0/doc/html/Foreign-StablePtr.html)), and export getter functions to access individual fields.

Please let me know if you need more details, and I'll expand the answer.

Comment: Looks good to me. I was wondering how would I go about returning a list of StablePtr somehow?

Comment: @JakubHampl you can try `Foreign.Marshal.Array.newArray` or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a little tool (using Template Haskell), that does automagically marshal any data type that consists of primitive types (Int, Float, Double, Char, Bool), List of a marshallable type, and structs consisting of marshallable types into a corresponding C type.

- Primitive types become their C counterparts: Int -> int, Float -> float. Bool becomes int.
- "Structs" (data S = S ...) become pointers to a struct with marshalled members of the Haskell "struct".
- Arrays ([S]) become pointers to a struct consisting of a pointer to an array of pointers to that type, and an int, telling how many elements are in there.

So this:

```
data Test = Test [MyStruct] Int
data MyStruct = MyStruct Int
```

would look like this in C:

```
struct MyStruct {
  int x;
}

struct ArrayStruct {
  MyStruct** array;
  int count;
}

struct Test {
  ArrayStruct* arr_str;
  int y;
}
```

Here is the tool:
https://github.com/food2games/fieldmarshal

(It also has a C# part, but you will need HsFieldMarshal.) It consists of two files, you just have to copy them to your code. Usage:

```
$(makeStorable ''YourType)
```

Please note, that it doesn't do Storable code automatically for subtypes, so if you have this:

```
data Type1 = Type1 Int Float
data Type2 = Type2 Int Type1
```

than you have to generate Storable instances to each data type:

```
$(makeStorable ''Type1)
$(makeStorable ''Type2)
```

Also note, that you have to declare data types earlier than the Storable instance generation (it's because of TH). So this won't work:

```
$(makeStorable ''Wrong)
data Wrong = Wrong Int
```

This is absolutely not foolproof, it's enough for simple apps, but if you are working with a more complex code, things can get messed up pretty easily.

Comment: Looks pretty cool, but I do get some errors when using it. First of all, supporting C strings would be quite useful. Secondly I get `FieldMarshal.hs:(172,1)-(176,61): Non-exhaustive patterns in function makeDataType` when generating [RefType](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/citeproc-hs/0.3.6/doc/html/Text-CSL-Reference.html#t:RefType).

Comment: From @nulloid (he can't comment on this post, so I'm posting his comment): Yup, that was planned, but I had memory management problems. Also I don't need that feature currently, so I didn't put much effort into it.

Comment: Also from @nulloid (too long for one comment): 
"Secondly I get FieldMarshal.hs:(172,1)-(176,61): Non-exhaustive patterns in function makeDataType when generating RefType."

It's probably because FieldMarshal doesn't support types with more than 1 constructors. (I think it could be done with C unions...)

Sorry, I should've read your question more carefully. Also, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Final part of @nulloid's comment: (Unfortunately I don't have the time to work actively on features I don't need. However, I can help if someone wants to understand and modify the code. But if you don't need to extensively create wrappers (I did), then probably you should just write a marshaller by hand.)

Comment: Appears the url https://github.com/food2games/fieldmarshal died.  Any idea who that was or where they went?